# Solution to a first-order, nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to get the solution set to $y^{\prime} + y^{2} = 0$ in the set of continuously differentiable functions defined on the interval $(0, \infty)$. At least I need to know that this set consists of more than the zero function.  Ironically, this is for a course in Linear Algebra, the prerequisite of which is a course in ordinary differential equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the equation like this

$-\frac{dy}{y^2} = dx$

And then use $ (\frac{1}{y})' = -\frac{dy}{y^2}$

You then get

$\frac{1}{y} = x + C \Rightarrow y = \frac{1}{x+C}$

where $C$   is the integration constant

Comment: That is a very nice, terse explanation!